# Find next available cell and paste the data

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet

I'm trying to update value in the next cell.
For example, in cell "A1", I have name. When I click on a button, the value in A1 has to go to cell "A1" in Sheet2. And once that is done, as and when I put new values Sheet1("A1") the data has to get reflected in next cells in Sheet2 (i.e A2, A3, A4 etc).

I tried almost every YouTube video, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Youtube is NOT a good place to be learning how to write code. Please include your code in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727084/vba-paste-value-to-next-empty-cell-in-a-range?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please state what you’ve tried and why it doesn’t work in future posts.
This can help you:

```
Sub CellEqCell()

 Dim ws1 as worksheet
 Dim ws2 as worksheet
 Set ws1 = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)
 Set ws2 = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(“Sheet2”)

 Ws2.Range(“A1”).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Value =
 ws1.Range(“A1”).Value
 
End sub
```

This should take into account your last row, and set cells equal to one another without copy/paste.

Comment: Hi Kleven, I tried, but it isn't working... I'm getting "Application-defined or object-defined" error".